# Passing cookies from jax-rx rest api end point to ejb

Tags: ejb, thread-local

I am looking for a solution related to passing cookies values from JAX-RX REST API endpoint to ejb layer.

I tried searching the solution and found some of them are using thread local. but and thread local supposed to be not working with executor services.

Is there any another solution that I can use to pass cookies values from web/rest later to ejb layer.

Note: I do not want to pass it as method parameter from rest layer to down the ejb layer. I would like to access the cookies values directly in ejb layer

Thanks

Comment: You need to show some of your code because there is some implication above that you're attempting to use EE Concurrency Utilities in your EJBs. Are you just concerned with security identity from the cookies?

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have a class `MyEJB`, you can inject `HttpServletRequest` object to you *ejb* as follows:

```
public class MyEJB{
    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest httpRequest;
}
```

Now from this request object you can access your required cookies. As follows:

```
String rawCookie = request.getHeader("Cookie");
String[] rawCookieParams = rawCookie.split(";");
for(String rawCookieNameAndValue :rawCookieParams)
{
  String[] rawCookieNameAndValuePair = rawCookieNameAndValue.split("=");
}
```

Comment: I do not think this should work . As httpservletrequest context gives NPE when tries to access from EJB .